# ValueError when using cv2.findContours function in python

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
```

When test went there, an error occured`ValueError: too many values to unpack`, can anyone tell me why it happened since my opencv is 3.0.0 and the `findContours` return two values as said in Documents and how to solve this problem

After print the result of threshold function, it returns this

`(127.0, array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ..., 
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8))`

Comment: Please print out and report back what cv2.threshold really returns, *without* your unpacking into (ret, thresh)

Comment: Can you also post your full traceback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"since my opencv is 3.0.0 and the findContours return two values" - you're [wrong](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.findContours) about this:

```
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

see, it returns 3 values, an additional image (that you should discard)

Comment: oh, yes, thank you. After I add a useless image, the test run well~~

Comment: yes, indeed, the image is useless in this case. (but note, that a lot of 3.0 python functions (like all the drawing stuff) differ in the same way, and return an additional image [for chaining, i guess])